# How to implement Sha3Algorithm Adjust difficulty

Tags: substrate

I've succesfully created a proof of work node with a constant as difficulty.
Now i've created the sha3algorithm struct that should fetch the difficulty from the runtime

```
                let pow_block_import = sc_consensus_pow::PowBlockImport::new(
                    client.clone(),
                    client.clone(),
                    crate::pow::Sha3Algorithm::new(client.clone()),
                    0,
                    select_chain,
                    inherent_data_providers.clone()
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your runtime apis

```
    impl sp_consensus_pow::DifficultyApi<Block, U256> for Runtime {
        fn difficulty() -> U256 {
            U256::from(10000000)
        }
    }
```

From here you can call any module that calculates the difficulty